# Creating Linked List in C using for loop for assigning values

Tags: c, for-loop, linked-list, malloc, structure

I am trying to create a linked list for my program using a for loop which assigning values. In the creation of this linked list, I want to be able to keep track of the head and have the first value in the for loop assigned to the head. For example, if I am creating a list from 0 to n - 1, I want the head to point to 0 and the rest of the list to be followed by 1-2-3-4-...-n-1. I have programmed a loop that does just that, however, the for loop has to count down backward instead of forward. Here is my code:

```
// Structure
typedef struct node {
  int value;
  struct node * next;
} ListNode;

  int size = "some value"; 

  ListNode * head = NULL; // beginning of the linked list
  ListNode * temp; // temporary node  

  for(int count = size - 1; count >= 0; count--)
  {
    // creates temporary nodes //
    ListNode * tempNode = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    tempNode -> value = count;
    tempNode -> next = NULL;
    // creation of node completed

    temp = tempNode;
    temp -> next = head;
    head = temp;
  }
```

Although in this program the head points to 0 as I intend, is there a way to have the for loop start from 0 all the way up until n and still produce the same output. I would like it to look like (int for count = 0; count < n; count++). It is just a preference thing that I was wondering was possible. Please help if you know, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in your code, you don't need the extra `tempNode`, just use `temp` and make it local to the inner block:

```
for (int count = size; count--; ) {
    ListNode *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));

    temp->value = count;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}
```

If you want to append elements at the end, you should keep a pointer to the last node, the `tail`:

```
ListNode *head = NULL;
ListNode *tail = NULL;

for (int count = 0; count < size; count++) {
    ListNode *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));

    temp->value = count;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if (tail == NULL) {
        head = temp;
        tail = temp;
    } else {
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
}
```

There is a more elegant way to do this: Instead of keeping a pointer to the last node, keep a pointer to the null pointer where the next element should go:

```
ListNode *head = NULL;
ListNode **tail = &head;

for (int count = 0; count < size; count++) {
    ListNode *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));

    temp->value = count;
    temp->next = NULL;

    *tail = temp;
    tail = &(*tail)->next;
}
```

At the beginning, `*tail` holds the address of `head`, after that it will hold the address of the `next` member of the last node. You can update both via the pointer `tail` without the need to check whether the list is empty or not.

This last method looks a bit daunting at first with its `ListNode **tail`, but once you get the hang of it, it's a useful tool to have. If you don't feel comfortable with it (yet), use the first variant.

Is it worth the effort only to create the list forwards? Insertion to a list at the front is easy and after tidying up, your original variant looks clean and compact to me.